# Huge "Data" when using DiskUsage in Innternal Memory

Tags: internal-storage

My Lenovo P770's internal memory usage is very large – although I have deleted some unimportant data/apps. This is what it looks like using DiskUsage application:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

I noticed that theres a huge "Data" (755 MB) in my internal storage. 
What is this data? Is it save to delete it? How to do it (where is it's location)?

Sorry for much questions, please help me out. Thanks a lot

Note: I have used CCleaner but it doesn't help much. I think the main problem is this huge "Data".

Comment: As the screenshot shows, the "huge data" is mostly "applications" (each column represents a "detail view" of the one left to it). From the apps, most space is consumed by Facebook and Twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the right, it contains the private data for all apps. If you want to delete these data, you can do it by uninstalling apps or by clicking "Clear data" in the apps manager.

Comment: How do i know which apps have that huge data? Thanks

Comment: You can see in your screenshot. Facebook is using 122.9 MiB, Twitter is using 90.4 MiB, etc. On recent Android versions, the same data are available in the apps manager: each app shows how much space it takes up, and you can sort largest-first.

Comment: Do you mean that "Data" is "Applications" + "System data" + "Free space" ?

Comment: Yes, that's how the app works. Everything to the right is inside the thing on its left.

Comment: Okay, i will try to do something (i think i have moved all of the apps data to the USB storage). Thanks, i will let you know what happened.

Comment: Wait, so if the total data is 755 MB, i should have around 1,2 GB free data because my internal memory is 2GB. How much does Jellybean OS cost?

Comment: Comments aren't for extended discussions. You asked a question, I answered it. If you have a bigger problem to solve, either ask it as a new question (and be sure to give all the details), or come join us in [chat].